# In Eclipse, can I add code formatter to existing editor

Tags: eclipse, plugins, formatting, editor, editing

So here is the case, I have custom javascript based language, which comes with its nice editor and tools, installed as plugin in Eclipse. The problem is there is no code formatter and I need to edit each line by hand.
I have tested the JS forrmater on this code and it works fine, since the two languages are quite similar. Basically  *I need to somehow link/add/apply the formatter  to this code editor*.

**The general question, I have two code editors A and B. Can I edit the code using the code editor from A and format the code using the code formatter from B.**

My progress so far ( after digging in the internet ).
I have come up with some solutions, but they are not quite easy to use or configure.

- create batch/shell cron job to listen for any changes in your files, and use some cli tool like [js-beautify](https://www.npmjs.com/package/js-beautify) to automatically format the code. Not very handy because you need to refresh the files, and there are no cool things like save actions for example
- suggested by many forums, implement your own eclipse plugin, problem is (in my case) that this plugin comes as a third party to me and I can't be part of its release process.

Any help will be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You can write an external plug-in to what is already in place, it does not have to edit the existing code or be part of that release. The plug-in can then implement "save actions".

For example, the [AnyEdit](http://andrei.gmxhome.de/anyedit/) plug-in trims trailing whitespace as part of save on any editor if you have AnyEdit installed. So I would look at that [EPL source code](https://github.com/iloveeclipse/anyedittools) and see if you can spin your own solution easily enough. If you are not sure where to start, perhaps look at where it is [hooked in](https://github.com/iloveeclipse/anyedittools/blob/ab77b45/AnyEditTools/src/de/loskutov/anyedit/actions/internal/StartupHelper2.java#L287):

```java
private void hookOnCommand(String commandId) {
        ICommandService service = (ICommandService) PlatformUI.getWorkbench().getService(
                ICommandService.class);
        Command command = service.getCommand(commandId);
        PreExecutionHandler listener = new PreExecutionHandler(commandId);
        command.addExecutionListener(listener);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the comment, indeed this any edit tool is good, but it has no functionality for beautifying the code. Like the JS plugin does. I need to defined the code style conventions (like it is done in the java formatter) and give them to anyone else contributing to the project (in xml format for example)

Comment: @BorislavStoilov I was not recommending AnyEdit as the final solution for your problem, rather it shows how to hook in save actions. Using such hooks you can resolve your " general question, I have two code editors A and B. Can I edit the code using the code editor from A and format the code using the code formatter from B."